# Bottom growth of corn plant is yellow and brown, top is healthy

Tags: plant-care

[image]

Any ideas what is going on with this week plant?

Answer (score 1):

The plant has been overwatered and that combined with competition from the taller stem has caused the smaller one to die slowly.  There are a [number](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/9003/499) of [similar](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/16148/499) [questions](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/5337/499) about your plant, [Dracaena Fragrans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dracaena_fragrans).

You are best off to let the smaller stem die back and then twist the stem out of the pot and throw it away.  The larger stem will be just fine if you reduce your water, increase your light and check for [spider mites](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/2994/499) on the underside of the leaves.